# Can't save user data from backend to the redux state as long as the user is authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to show the user name on the home page when he authenticates, so on the backend and at the login endpoint i put a user object in the json response `(res.json)` containing the name and email of the user thats going to be sent to the client side as a response to the login redux action that will get the user object from `res.data` and send it to the reducer that will save that user object to the redux state . When i login everything is working fine the data is displayed like i want but when i change any random thing about anything else and the page refresh when i save i get the error that the user data is not available

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" from user.name

so the user data is not saved in the state permanently.

I thought there where a problem with the mongodb but everything is fine 
i got the mapstatetoprops like i should the proptypes and the connect method but my components dont have a constructor.

the backend code for sending the data

```
            if (isMatch) {

                // User matched
                // Create JWT Payload
                const payload = {
                    id: user.id,
                    name: user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
                };

                // Sign token
                jwt.sign(
                    payload,

                    keys.secretOrKey,
                    {
                        expiresIn: 31556926 // 1 year in seconds
                    },
                    (err, token) => {
                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            token: "Bearer " + token,
                            user: {
                                name: user.first_name + " " + user.last_name,
                                email: user.email
                            }
                        });
                    }
                );
            }
```

frontend :

```
render() {
        const { user } = this.props.auth;
        return (
            <div style={{ height: "75vh" }} className="container valign-wrapper">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 center-align">
                        <h4>
                            <b>Hey there,</b> {user.name}
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
WelcomeDashboard.propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { logoutUser }
)(WelcomeDashboard);
```

I expect the user data to always be available and don't get lost and undifined whenever i make changes and the page refreshes

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when the page
>   refreshes from "{user.name}

but when i logout and login again i don't get the error only when i change some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are having rest-full API implementation, you cannot get any help from your backend. So it is not the issue with MongoDB.

When going through your questions I have a few suggestions to get rid of this issue.

1. You can save the current redux state into your browser local storage. Below code segment shows how to do it for your authReducer.

```
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

// your authReducer here

const authPersistConfig = {
    key: 'auth',
    storage: storage,
};

export default persistReducer(authPersistConfig, authReducer);
```

2. In the main component that shows after authentication (like dashboard or nav bar or the main App), you can fire another API call to validation your current JWT token and bring back the user details as you do in login request. (JWT token should be saved in local storage)

Those are a few options, you can choose one that you are very familiar with.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you  i tried sending the data i need with the token and everything works fine